# How to simplify adding multiple text inputs

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

i have an application in which i have around 100 textinputs all are numbers

i want to simplify the addition ie. any other way than saying **txt1.text+txt2.text.....**

that would increase *my code a lot*

is it possible to have (n+=txt*.text) or some thing like that

any help would be appreciated have to get the application done in two days thank you

Answer (score 1):

If `txt1`, `txt2` etc are public properties of the class representing `this`, you can use the following code to get the sum of the numbers in the text inputs.

```
var n:Number = 0;
for(i = 1; i <= total; i++)
  n += Number(this["txt" + i].text);
```

To get a concatenated string:

```
var s:String = "";
for(i = 1; i <= total; i++)
  s += this["txt" + i].text;
```

If the text inputs are properties of a different class, use the instance name of the object instead of `this`. For example:

```
instanceName["txt" + i].text;
```

Another solution that is more clean is to store them in an array and loop through them. But that might require changes in other parts of your code.